# Repeatable iOS app crash when when editing extremely long post

Tags: bug, ios-app

I am experiencing repeatable crashes when editing an extremely long post via the iOS app.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6 Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit my 2nd most recent post on EL&U¹
2. Hit edit
3. Scroll to the bottom, between footnotes 5 and 6 reliably crashes for me
4. Long-tap to insert the cursor immediately after the `</sub>` of footnote 5
5. You may have to long-tap twice; once to put you in edit mode, and again to move the cursor where you want it. The app seems to get confused about cursor placement.
6. Hit enter twice

Video of crash and steps to reproduce (too big to embed here):

> [http://i.imgur.com/O8AZoot.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/O8AZoot.gifv)

Step 3 seems to be important. Or, at least, I get the crash very reliably adding material towards the end of the post, but only intermittently if I do the same steps near the top of the post.

I can edit the post just fine using Chrome on my laptop.

---

¹ <sub>I won't link to it directly, it's attracted too much attention already.</sub>